# sql query to count various fields in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having enquiry table and the fields are below

```
sno     confname         region       enquiry   status update    closed      approval
 1     Conf 2020     Madhya Pradesh     test           test      closed      reconsider
 2     Conf 2013     Maharashtra       test 123        abcde                reconsider
 3     Conf 2013     Maharashtra        test12         test      closed      approved
 4     Conf 2013     Maharashtra        test124       test1      closed      approved 
 5     Conf 3        Karnataka          test124       test1                  
 6     Conf 3        Karnataka          test876       test45       
 7     Conf 3        Karnataka          test365       test45      closed     approved
```

and I need the output as

```
Region          Conf Name    Total No of Enq   No of Enq Closed    No of Enq Approved 
Maharashtra     Conf 2013                3                2                        2
Karnataka       Conf 3                   3                1                        1
Madhya Pradesh  Conf 2020                1                1
```

and my sql query is

```
SELECT confname,
       region,
       clsed ,
       apprstatus ,
       Count(region) AS totenq,
       Count(clsed) AS totenqclsd ,
       COUNT(apprstatus) AS totenqapproved
FROM [enquiries_dtls]
GROUP BY region,
         confname,
         clsed,
         apprstatus
```

Comment: use concatenate the output with the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
select region,
  confname,
  count(*) TotalEnquiry,
  sum(case when closed is not null then 1 else 0 end) TotalClosed,
  sum(case when approval = 'approved' then 1 else 0 end) TotalApproved
from enquiries_dtls
group by region, confname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7db0f/1)

Edit, If you need to calculate another value based on these columns, then use a subquery:

```
select region,
  confname,
  TotalEnquiry,
  TotalClosed, 
  TotalApproved,
  TotalEnquiry - TotalApproved 
from
(
  select region,
    confname,
    count(*) TotalEnquiry,
    sum(case when closed is not null then 1 else 0 end) TotalClosed,
    sum(case when approval = 'approved' then 1 else 0 end) TotalApproved
  from enquiries_dtls
  group by region, confname
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7db0f/2)

Comment: In this i need to find the number of enquiries pending. This has to come from the difference of TotalEnquiry - TotalApproved

Comment: @Affan Please post a new question if you have one. :)

Comment: i need the answer for this task only..i need to calculate the difference between the Total no of Enquiries and Total number of enquiries approved..need to subtract these two values